# Generate pre-signed url for S3 client-side encrypted file to view/open

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

Using AWS-C++ SDK on Windows, I am uploading an object(mp4 file) using client-side encryption(AWS KMS) and generating the pre-signed url for it. The upload works fine but generated pre-signed url doesn't play it. It seems that it tries to play the encrypted data.

I also tried the txt file but it downloads the encrypted file when url is opened.

If I use server-side encryption then url works.

I want to use client-side encryption to protect data in transit and creating a pre-signed url which show/play the unencrypted file. Is this possible? 
Is there anyway to play the encrypted mp4 file?

Please suggest.

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-signed URL will retrieve the file exactly as it was uploaded to S3.

Since S3 server-side saw the data already encrypted (since it was encrypted client-side), it returns that same encrypted data.

If your data is encrypted client-side, you must decrypt the data after downloading the data using the pre-signed URL.

Browsers won't do this natively for you. You'll need to handle your own decryption.

If you ensure that you are using HTTPS for the upload and download, then you should not need to be concerned about encrypting the data during transmission because it will be encrypted at the transport level. You can add a bucket policy to your S3 bucket that ensures only HTTPS is used to read/write data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you just download the file from S3 its still encrypted. You cannot simply display the pre-signed URL to your user as their browser will not be able to decrypt the file.

You could create a play button. When the button was clicked it would download the file, decrypt it (using the KMS part of the SDK) and start playing it.

Here is [an example in the .NET SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/kms-keys-s3-encryption.html). I couldn't find any references in the C++ SDK, it appears to be poorly documented.